# Regex to PHP regex !A to [^A]

Tags: php, regex, converters

Hi fellow programmers.

So i am trying to make covertion to PHP regex and I got stuck on converting !A to [^A]

```
    $string = "!A!Bb%!C!";
    $string =  preg_replace("/(?<=(?<!%)!.)/", "]" , $string ); 
    $string =  preg_replace("/(?<!%)!(?=.)/", "[^" , $string);
```

which works fine but when string is with two !! next to each other its not working for example like this "!A!!Bb%!C!" and the % is nullying the negation.

try here http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: What kind of regex format is `!A`? Why not just write your irregular expressions as **regular** expressions?

Comment: its part of bigger project and they are using it like !A somewhere else and it needs to be converted

Comment: We need to understand it before we can help you. Do you have any kind of documentation?

Comment: This is pretty much last thing I have to do. And documentation is not very much specific about this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `/.(?<=!)(\w)/g` and replace with `[^\1]`

which when takes an input string as `!A!Bb%!C!`

will output

`[^A][^B]b%[^C]!`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/tX2gR1

Comment: How do you know what the output should look like?

Comment: He wants to take some string and make a regex out of it, may be its his first shot at it and this can be something to get him going

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I was looking for except when I use it on server output is [^]![^]b%[^]! instead of [^A][^B]b%[^C]! but when i try it on sites it works how it should be. Any idea how to fix it? Probably I should somehow change replacement.
Thanks for quick reply!

Comment: i think your capture groups are not coming in, make sure you have captured the letters in `(\w)` I dont know what you are using to get your backreferences, you can try `$1` instead of `\1`, just guessing

Comment: Silly me I should have figured it by myself it rly is $1. U saved me a lot of time, thank you guys!

Comment: @Anymoify don't forget to mark the answer as correct if you get your doubts cleared :)